# Generating an IPA file for a flutter project without a paid dev account

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, apple-id

so I just finished a Flutter mobile app and I want to install on my personal iPhone. I know about the 7 days restriction, but buy an apple dev account for 99$/year was a bit too much for me so I used an external service. You pay them a lil bit of money and give them your iPhone's udid and they give you back the certificate and provisioning profile files and you can use an external signer to sign your apps. I have already done this for an app of mine a few month ago. But now I'm struggling with generating the ipa.
How can I generate the ipa file with the free apple account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He again, so the way to generate an unsigned flutter ipa is by first going to Xcode and changing the build configuration of the scheme to `Release` :

1. Click on Runner, and Edit scheme

[image]

2. Select Release for the Build Configuration of the Run schema

[image]

And then on the terminal in Android Studio run the following command :

```
flutter build ios --release
```

This will take a minute or two and when it's done go to this folder : `your-app/build/ios/Release-iphoneos` and you should find your `runner.app` file. Create a folder named `PayLoad` next to it and copy and paste the `runner.app` file inside this folder. After that you wanna compress your `Payload` to get a new file named `Payload.zip`. Change its extension to `ipa` and you're done.
You can now use whatever you want to codesign this ipa file.

Comment: You can not build IPA for device without a provisioning profile & certificate.

Comment: I changed my post so that it's hopefully clearer now, what I meant is how to generate an ipa with a free apple account.

Comment: this is the error it showed me can you help,"It appears that your application still contains the default
signing identifier.
Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:"

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't install it on an iPhone. Any sugguestion?